# How to annotate every frame with gcp video intelligence detect pose

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, cloud, artificial-intelligence

google cloud platform provides video intelligence framework to detect person landmarks in video. Sample code is from [gcp documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/people-detection).

I'm struggling to find a way to force the framework to annotated **every single frame** of the video, as this call returns only timestamps of 0.1 seconds. I only could think of a hack of manually triple length of the video (that is 30fps) to get annotation per every frame, but I really don't like the idea of doing that.

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Sample code:

```py
import io

from google.cloud import videointelligence_v1 as videointelligence


def detect_person(local_file_path="path/to/your/video-file.mp4"):
    """Detects people in a video from a local file."""

    client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()

    with io.open(local_file_path, "rb") as f:
        input_content = f.read()

    # Configure the request
    config = videointelligence.types.PersonDetectionConfig(
        include_bounding_boxes=True,
        include_attributes=True,
        include_pose_landmarks=True,
    )
    context = videointelligence.types.VideoContext(person_detection_config=config)

    # Start the asynchronous request
    operation = client.annotate_video(
        request={
            "features": [videointelligence.Feature.PERSON_DETECTION],
            "input_content": input_content,
            "video_context": context,
        }
    )

    print("\nProcessing video for person detection annotations.")
    result = operation.result(timeout=300)

    print("\nFinished processing.\n")

    # Retrieve the first result, because a single video was processed.
    annotation_result = result.annotation_results[0]

    for annotation in annotation_result.person_detection_annotations:
        print("Person detected:")
        for track in annotation.tracks:
            print(
                "Segment: {}s to {}s".format(
                    track.segment.start_time_offset.seconds
                    + track.segment.start_time_offset.microseconds / 1e6,
                    track.segment.end_time_offset.seconds
                    + track.segment.end_time_offset.microseconds / 1e6,
                )
            )

            # Each segment includes timestamped objects that include
            # characteristic - -e.g.clothes, posture of the person detected.
            # Grab the first timestamped object
            timestamped_object = track.timestamped_objects[0]
            box = timestamped_object.normalized_bounding_box
            print("Bounding box:")
            print("\tleft  : {}".format(box.left))
            print("\ttop   : {}".format(box.top))
            print("\tright : {}".format(box.right))
            print("\tbottom: {}".format(box.bottom))

            # Attributes include unique pieces of clothing,
            # poses, or hair color.
            print("Attributes:")
            for attribute in timestamped_object.attributes:
                print(
                    "\t{}:{} {}".format(
                        attribute.name, attribute.value, attribute.confidence
                    )
                )

            # Landmarks in person detection include body parts such as
            # left_shoulder, right_ear, and right_ankle
            print("Landmarks:")
            for landmark in timestamped_object.landmarks:
                print(
                    "\t{}: {} (x={}, y={})".format(
                        landmark.name,
                        landmark.confidence,
                        landmark.point.x,  # Normalized vertex
                        landmark.point.y,  # Normalized vertex
                    )
                )
```

Attributes of the `PersonDetectionConfig`

```py
"""
Attributes:
    include_bounding_boxes (bool):
        Whether bounding boxes are included in the
        person detection annotation output.
    include_pose_landmarks (bool):
        Whether to enable pose landmarks detection. Ignored if
        'include_bounding_boxes' is set to false.
    include_attributes (bool):
        Whether to enable person attributes detection, such as cloth
        color (black, blue, etc), type (coat, dress, etc), pattern
        (plain, floral, etc), hair, etc. Ignored if
        'include_bounding_boxes' is set to false.
"""
```

Sample output

```
Landmarks: 2.5025s
    nose: 0.7880418300628662 (x=0.10155333578586578, y=0.29470884799957275)
    left_eye: 0.8498712182044983 (x=0.10444415360689163, y=0.2844345271587372)
    right_eye: 0.05180135369300842 (x=0.1029987558722496, y=0.28700312972068787)
    left_ear: 0.8830078840255737 (x=0.11745283752679825, y=0.28700312972068787)
    right_ear: 0.03634342923760414 (x=0.12757070362567902, y=0.28957170248031616)
    left_shoulder: 0.8504171371459961 (x=0.1145620197057724, y=0.34094318747520447)
    right_shoulder: 0.7254488468170166 (x=0.14925184845924377, y=0.34351176023483276)
    left_elbow: 0.7874324321746826 (x=0.10444415360689163, y=0.4205690324306488)
    right_elbow: 0.873414158821106 (x=0.18249624967575073, y=0.4154318571090698)
    left_wrist: 0.8134297132492065 (x=0.07987220585346222, y=0.44882336258888245)
    right_wrist: 0.5310596227645874 (x=0.1579243242740631, y=0.4693719446659088)
    left_hip: 0.48307809233665466 (x=0.12901613116264343, y=0.5130376815795898)
    right_hip: 0.4054966866970062 (x=0.14347021281719208, y=0.507900595664978)
    left_knee: 0.707266092300415 (x=0.14057938754558563, y=0.6363293528556824)
    right_knee: 0.536503791809082 (x=0.1029987558722496, y=0.615780770778656)
    left_ankle: 0.6422659158706665 (x=0.21429529786109924, y=0.6620150804519653)
    right_ankle: 0.7963647842407227 (x=0.08276302367448807, y=0.7467780113220215)
Landmarks: 2.6026s
    nose: 0.6816550493240356 (x=0.030738139525055885, y=0.3216055631637573)
    left_eye: 0.7059812545776367 (x=0.03222046047449112, y=0.3110688030719757)
    right_eye: 0.038844481110572815 (x=0.030738139525055885, y=0.3110688030719757)
    left_ear: 0.7951924800872803 (x=0.045561421662569046, y=0.3110688030719757)
    right_ear: 0.03984677046537399 (x=0.05742005258798599, y=0.3110688030719757)
    left_shoulder: 0.812483012676239 (x=0.047043751925230026, y=0.36638668179512024)
    right_shoulder: 0.7965729236602783 (x=0.08113731443881989, y=0.36375248432159424)
    left_elbow: 0.614456295967102 (x=0.05000840872526169, y=0.45331475138664246)
    right_elbow: 0.589381992816925 (x=0.10040760785341263, y=0.45331475138664246)
    left_wrist: 0.6238939762115479 (x=0.029255803674459457, y=0.49809587001800537)
    right_wrist: 0.31396669149398804 (x=0.0796549841761589, y=0.49282753467559814)
    left_hip: 0.3904641270637512 (x=0.05890238285064697, y=0.5376086235046387)
    right_hip: 0.3786430358886719 (x=0.0796549841761589, y=0.5323402285575867)
    left_knee: 0.46311870217323303 (x=0.035185132175683975, y=0.648244321346283)
    right_knee: 0.33408626914024353 (x=0.0411144383251667, y=0.6429758667945862)
```

Comment: Hey did you got the answer, if yes please, post

Comment: @ArnavMehta i did not

Comment: So what you did?

Comment: @ArnavMehta nothing